# vue js axios, send a POST to elasticsearch

Tags: vue.js, elasticsearch, post, axios

In Vue JS using Axios I'd like to make a `POST` request to an Elasticsearch instance. More precisely I'd like to store a search template (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#pre-registered-templates)

```
POST _scripts/<templateid> {
    "script": {
        "lang": "mustache",
        "source": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "{{query_string}}"
                }
            }
        }
    } }
```

It works with CURL but I'm getting an error 400 when I'm trying with Axios.
My code is the following (with `test` as templateid)

```js
var dataBody = {
        "script": {
          "lang": "mustache",
          "source": {
            "query": { 
              "match": {
                "keyword": {
                  "query": "{{search_term}}"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      };

      this.$http.post(
        "https://es-url/_scripts/test",
        {
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: "json",
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("elastic:password")
          },
          params: {
            source: dataBody,
            source_content_type: 'application/json'
          }
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:61)
```

I'm using the same Axios parameters to retrieve data (from my search queries), it works just fine, the difference is I can use `GET` for my search queries while I need to use `POST` to store a search template.

Comment: You sure you're using Axios? That looks more like a jQuery `$.ajax()` call

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got Axios and jQuery's `$.ajax` mixed up.

If you are actually using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config), it would look like this

```js
this.$http.post('https://es-url/_scripts/test', dataBody, {
  auth: {
    username: 'elastic',
    password: 'password'
  }
})
```

---

Note that for this to work, you would need Elasticsearch configured with `http.cors.enabled=true`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, do i need to execute PUT _cluster/settings
{
   "persistent" : {
      "http.cors.enabled" : true
   }
} 

I tried but im getting "persistent setting [http.cors.enabled], not dynamically updateable". thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @woshitom I haven't used Elasticsearch much but the `http` settings should be set in your [configuration file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html) as it explains in the documentation I linked in my answer